# Limiting bandwith on an Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-7, networking, bandwidth, cable-modem

I need to limit the bandwidth on my Windows 7 x64 machine.

In the past (on XP) I've been able to use NetLimiter for similar tasks. However for some reason I can't get it to work anymore. For lower limits the bandwidth tests are able to exceed the limit by 10-50%; higher limits seem to be ignored completely and the bandwidth tests report download speeds of over 10 times the speed I set. I'm using speedtest.net and some similar service from my ISP for these tests.

Anyway, I don't necessarily need a program as complex as NetLimiter since I only need to throttle my machine's bandwidth, not a specific program's.

In case you are wondering why in the world I'd want to cripple my Internet speed, there is a funny story behind this. Long story short, my modem gets random disconnects. Tech support comes in, says my Internet speed is abnormally high and I must be using some tools to somehow make it go faster than it's supposed to and this messes up my modem. I check the connection with another computer and it seems that my PC is the only one in my network that gets abnormal speeds. I reinstall my OS, speed looks normal at first, after I install the batch of 50 or so updates, it goes back to abnormally high speeds and the disconnect problems are not solved.

Now I don't have a clue if the explanation the tech team gave me was just a strategy to lay the blame on someone else, but I was trying to give them the benefit of the doubt and see what happens if I really reduce my speed to their specification.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the app but if it's old enough, you might try disabling UAC.

Comment: You can't possibly make your Internet any faster then they allow.  Change ISPs, these guys don't sound too bright. :)   Also which version of NetLimiter are you using?  Version 3(+) supports Windows 7, but there's no freeware version of it (yet).

Comment: UAC is disabled. Yes, I'm using v.3. I think it's a trial, I don't need it for more than a week or 2. I know it sounds strange but the tests I do on speedtest.net on some servers show speeds of up to 3 times over my allotted bandwidth.

Comment: If you can get more speed than you're supposed to have, then that's your ISP's problem, not yours. If for some magic reason you *can* do this, and it's causing their equipment to become unstable then, again, that's their problem, not yours.  You pay THEM for stable Internet.

Comment: Can't argue with that :)

Answer (score 1):

Found this one for Windows using Fiddler (free)
http://www.logic-worx.com/index.php/tools-and-apps/fiddler-connection-simulator/

Else try this one:
http://www.akmalabs.com/downloads_netsim.php

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to sound paranoid, but this usually occurs if someone is tapping into your wifi. This is just a guess based on your description. You might want to apply a password to your network if you haven't already. Since you did an install of Windows 7, I'd assume that there's no virus, though it wouldn't hurt to check, either.

Comment: The post isn't saying that the problem is pulling down too much data over the connection (which would be what I'd expect if somebody was leeching wifi) the problem is that the raw connection speed is somehow magically higher than should be possible.  It's a question of rate, not volume....if anything somebody leeching would slow you down.